# Gulp with express inject custom path

Tags: gulp, mean-stack, gulp-inject

I'm using gulp on a mean stack. I've got my express static set like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
```

I'm using `gulp-inject` to inject my css and js to my html. However, since gulp is getting them from:

```
./client/libs/subfolder/subfolder.js
```

it also injects them as such. However due to my static settings it needs to resolve them from:

```
./libs/subfolder/subfolders.js
```

The gulp-inject docs aren't helping me, or i'm overlooking something.

Current gulpfiles.js inject task:

```
gulp.task('inject', function () {
    var customFiles = gulp.src(['./client/modules/**/*.js', './client/modules/**/*.css'], {read:false});
    gulp.src('./client/index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(bowerFiles(), {read: false, name: 'bower'})))
        .pipe(inject(customFiles))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./client'))
});
```

How do I get the paths correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok maybe I am too late. But for others, the way to do this is to set

```
'ignorePath':'client'
```

Let me know if you need more code to understand.